# CheckedListBox SetItemChecked to false inside ItemCheck event

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `CheckedListBox` on a Winforms program that contains several checkboxes. Certain checkboxes should not be enabled when there is not text present in a textbox.  However, I understand that there is no property enabled for individual CheckedListBox items. So my idea was to SetCheckedItem to false if there is no text, but this is not working. The item is still checked after the code executes.  Is there something wrong with this code, or is there a better way to implement these check boxes?

```
void controls_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    if (controlCheckbox.Focused)
    {
        string item = controlCheckbox.SelectedItem.ToString();
        CheckState isChecked = e.NewValue;

        if (item.StartsWith("Outer"))
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(outerTextBox.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("There must be Outer text in order to show the Outer legend. Please input text into the Outer text box and try again.", "No Outer Text Present", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
                controlCheckbox.SetItemChecked(controlBitsCheckbox.Items.IndexOf("Outer Legend Displayed"), false);
            }
            else
            {
                outerPanel.Refresh();
            }
        }
    }
}
```